# Best practices миграция sql script с использованием нескольких баз данных

Tags: .net, шаблоны-проектирования, sql

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть в проекте мигратор для базы данных, раньше он работал для одной db и все было хорошо, сейчас количество серверов баз данных увеличилось в двое. Как лучше подойти к решению данной задачи. Понятно что будет два контекста. Сначала инициализировать один контекст, прогнать скрипты для одной базы, потом второй соотв. Либо сначала два инициализировать, и по уже по последовательности выполнять скрипты. Но держать два конекшена по моему не очень. Что подскажете, что посоветуете?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вы его используете? Перед "выкаткой" очередной версии программы мигрируете несколько баз до нужной-последней версии? Если да, то ваш вопрос практически не имеет смысла, так как данная процедура проделывается всего лишь один раз (пусть и перед каждым билдом, но единожды) и производительностью в несколько сек или количеством конекшенов, которые надо будет "держать" очень не долго вполне можно пренебречь.

Возможно есть какая-то специфика проекта, например: другое назначение мигратора или огромная БД, которая генерится "долго", а также количество серверов постоянно растет и вы хотите для ускорения процесса миграций использовать многопоточность? В таком случае конечно будет иметь смысл открывать сразу нужное количество конекшенов.